# AppleScript any way to change terminal directory immediately?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I have a script to:

1. open a terminal window, go to working directory
2. then, open a new terminal window, expected to be in the same working directory
3. then, create new tab and run a (background) server command
4. then, switch to the previous tab and type in another server command (but not executing it)

The script works. But as you can see, I have to switch the directory every time before executing a command in another window. Is there any way to make `do script "cd ~/projects/work-dir/"` take effect immediately, so when I do a `keystroke "n" using {command down}` next time, the terminal window will start in the same directory?

- By the way, changing dir with `do script "cd ~/projects/work-dir/"` works as expected (takes effect immediately, so new terminal windows will be in the same directory) *when you run the script from Script Editor*, but not when you run the script through `osascript` from a terminal window. When you run the script through `osascript`, it seems the `cd` commands are 'resovled' only when the script ends.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    
    tell front window to set position to {1296, 25}
    
    do script "cd ~/projects/work-dir/" in selected tab of the front window
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using {command down}
    end tell
    
    do script "cd ~/projects/work-dir/" in selected tab of the front window
    
    delay 1
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
    end tell
    
    do script "cd ~/projects/work-dir/" in selected tab of the front window
    
    do script "bin/webpack-dev-server" in selected tab of the front window
    
    delay 3
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 48 using {control down, shift down}
    end tell
    
    tell front window to set position to {1346, 180}
    
    delay 1
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "rails s"
    end tell
end tell
```

Update: I wrote a simpler script to test this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    
    tell front window to set position to {1296, 25}
    
    do script "cd ~/projects/work-dir/" in selected tab of the front window
    delay 1
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "n" using {command down}
end tell
```

If you run the script from `osascript`, you will see that the new terminal window (or tab) will still start at the home path, and the `cd` command only take effect after the script is ended (after the new window is open).

Answer (score 0):

Two things: First, Terminal has a `New tabs open with` preference that you can set to `same working directory`. You can also adjust a profile's settings so that it runs a shell command upon being opened.

Second, I borrowed a piece from another answer and put this together. Essentially, I moved the myriad tell blocks to outside of the main Terminal one — in most cases using a [handler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58151). There are other ways to do this but in general, it's best to avoid the needless nesting of tell blocks. This works both from Script Editor and when run in the terminal using `osascript` (or when run as an application).

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script ""
    
    do script "cd ~/Desktop/projs/" in selected tab of the front window
    delay 0.1
    do script "/bin/pwd" in selected tab of the front window
    
    my mkTab()
    do script "cd ~/Desktop/projs/" in selected tab of the front window
    delay 0.1
    do script "/usr/bin/top -n 8 -o cpu" in selected tab of the front window
    
    my mkTab()
    do script "cd ~/Desktop/projs/" in selected tab of the front window
    delay 0.1
    do script "/bin/pwd" in selected tab of the front window
    
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.3
    keystroke "rails s"
end tell

on mkTab()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
        delay 0.2
    end tell
end mkTab
```

NB I don't have any server software to run so instead I ran a command that stays active (e.g. top). Hopefully it will work with your requirements as well although you may need to adjust the delays. Also, in the other tabs, I run `pwd` just to confirm that the `cd` was successful and to ensure that each tab can function independently while the script is running.

Comment: Thanks! I did have `New tabs open with` preference set to the same directory. The issue is when running from `osascript`, the `cd` command just won't take effect until all commands are complete. I updated a simple test script in the question. But anyway thanks for helping!

Comment: I see what you mean. Then I edited your updated script by adding `display dialog "done"` and removing the delay and the 'system events' block so that the script would go directly from 'cd …' to 'display dialog'. The 'cd' command is run but as you indicate, the terminal does not return to the prompt. Then the dialogue pops up and after clicking a button, the dialogue goes away and the terminal is updated (including with what the dialogue returned). Strange behaviour.

Comment: I think you should probably unaccept my answer as I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: What about creating two scripts and calling them from the same terminal line (but separated with a `;`)? Include a single line in the first script, e.g. `tell app "terminal" to do script "cd newdir" in selected….` and save as an app. Put all else in second script. In terminal, run `osascript a.app ; osascript b.scpt`. FWIW, I've read that applescript doesn't run in parallel so there may be some forced latency.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I've unaccepted the answer. I think separating into two scripts could work, but that kind of defeats the reason, which was to simplify the code, no? I wish I could give your answer an upvote at least, but the system says I need more reputation to do that. But anyway, much appreciated!

Comment: It's all good. Regardless of anything else, you should remove the delay after the 'cd' command as it offers zero benefit and only delays the actual completion of the task. Hope you find a workable solution.